# Exclude Day of Week

Tags: sql-server, datepart

I'm trying to exlcude Thursdays from a date range in SQL Server

The following is what I came up with from other examples:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date_field) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (5)
```

This appears to be working but I wanted to see if there were any suggestions for improvement etc.

Thanks!

Comment: This is going to scan and unless you index a computed column (which will be tough for date/time calculations) I don't know that there's a way to fix that. But at the very least, [please stop using lazy shorthand like `dw`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, was unaware. Little bit snarky but at the very least, you got a view for your site.

Comment: I don't care about views on my site - it's not even my site. I do see the same types of patterns causing the same kinds of problems all the time. I was trying to offer some helpful advice. If you found that snarky, you might want to stay off the Internet.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I read into "lazy" and a link to your blog post a bit too much. Thanks for taking the time to respond. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `DATENAME()` function:

`select *
from table
where DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date_field) <> 'Thursday'`

Comment: Not sure if this would be a better solution in terms of performance, since the predicate still compares an *expression* containing a column, rather than just a column, to a value. Either way, this would make the query less universal, because the original approach allows you to use the query in *any* locale while this one would limit it to just any *English* locale. (Might still work for the OP, of course.)